# Universal Links/App Links doesn't open the app with URL redirection

Tags: ios-universal-links, applinks, android-app-links, universal-link

If I add my universal link (**XYZ.com**) for a Button onClick or any other action click, the app opens without any issues.

But my usecase is something like this,
There is a button in the website with an onClick to **ABC.com**
**ABC.com** opens in a new tab and it redirects to **XYZ.com** which is my universal Link.

Now **XYZ.com** only loads in the mobile browser without opening the installed application.

is there any method to open the application when a browser URL redirection happens?

I have tried to directly call the universal link. This works. But when a URL redirection happens The app does not get opened.